# How to approach CSS composition/inheritance tricky case styling buttons?

Tags: html, css

So I have two HTML buttons that have a class: `.btn`. 
The CSS selector has a `background-image: linear-gradient(...)`.

Now I want the buttons to differ only in the value of the `background-image` property, for instance one button's `linear-gradient(...)` to go from black to red and the other from black to blue.

How do I achieve this without having to create another selector repeating the content of the `.btn`? Having also in mind that I have other CSS selectors like `.btn:hover` and `.btn:active` that give the illusion of extending/removing the gradient when you hover on the button or leave it clicked.

I thought about taking the `background-image:....` property out to another selector like `.primary` and `.secondary` which I will then apply to the buttons as a classes as well. But what about `.btn:hover` which "effect" depends on the actual color the given button has?

Here is what described: https://codepen.io/alejo4373/pen/RqmoWL

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @ksav for the great suggestion on using custom properties. Unfortunately their solution doesn't use the power of custom properties. Since they cascade just like regular properties, we can keep all our styles in `.btn`, `.btn:hover`, and `.btn:active`, making them reliant on the custom properties, and just use `.btn--primary` and `.btn--secondary` to do nothing more than set the custom properties. Everything is centralized to exactly the class where it needs to be applied, and there's no duplication.

```css
.btn--primary {
  --btn-color-top: #15FF86;
  --btn-color-bottom: #68BB42;
}

.btn--secondary {
  --btn-color-top: #fcbfc4;
  --btn-color-bottom: #811a08;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(96, 96, 96);
  border: 1px solid #adadad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;

  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--btn-color-top) 0, var(--btn-color-bottom) 100%);
}

.btn:hover {
  background-position: 0 -5px;
  background-color: var(--btn-color-bottom);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: var(--btn-color-bottom);
  background-image: none;
  border-color: rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.15em 0.3em rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn--primary'> Primary </button>
<button class='btn btn--secondary'> Secondary </button>
```

This works because regardless of where the custom property is used (for example in the `background-image` property of `.btn` or the `background-color` property of `.btn:active`), the value that's resolved is whatever value is determined by normal css cascading rules -- even if that's a different rule from where it's referenced using `var`! So in the case of the primary button, the values of `--btn-color-top` and `--btn-color-bottom` are provided by the definitions in the `.btn--primary` block when they're called by `var` in the `.btn` and `.btn:active` blocks. And the same thing happens with `.btn--secondary`.

Note you could also save a class by using the primary styles as the default, and using `btn--secondary` as an override:

```css
.btn {
  --btn-color-top: #15FF86;
  --btn-color-bottom: #68BB42;

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(96, 96, 96);
  border: 1px solid #adadad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;

  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--btn-color-top) 0, var(--btn-color-bottom) 100%);
}

.btn--secondary {
  --btn-color-top: #fcbfc4;
  --btn-color-bottom: #811a08;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-position: 0 -5px;
  background-color: var(--btn-color-bottom);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: var(--btn-color-bottom);
  background-image: none;
  border-color: rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.15em 0.3em rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'> Primary </button>
<button class='btn btn--secondary'> Secondary </button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Could you expand of whats going on here, it's not very clear to me yet. I read on CSS custom properties but I'm still trying to make sense of the way you used them here. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to add some more explanation. Custom properties are maybe a bit unintuitive but once you get your head around them they're super powerful. Best way I've found to understand them is just playing around with them. I'm going to reorder the css a little bit too; the order doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a second class for the alternative colouring.Here's an example with the class `.alt` which changes the background gradient to blue. You haven't provided your `:hover` CSS but this appears to work nicely with the hover in either the red or blue case, without needing more than the single line of styling for `.alt`.

Let me know if your `:hover` code is more complicated and I can have a further play. If you're using SCSS then life is a bit easier as you can do something like the following:

```
.alt {

    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,black 0,blue 100%);

    &:hover {

       // Extra styling   

    }

}
```

```css
.btn {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(96,96,96);
  border: 1px solid #adadad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,black 0,red 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #68BB42;
  border-color: #adadad;
  background-position: 0 -5px;
}

.alt {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,black 0,blue 100%);

}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #279f43;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: rgba(27,31,35,0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.15em 0.3em rgba(27,31,35,0.15);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class='btn'> Primary </button>
  <button class='btn alt'> Secondary </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a preprocessor, consider using [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) to store your color variables.

```css
.btn {
  --primary-top: #15FF86;
  --primary-bottom: #68BB42;
  
  --secondary-top: #fcbfc4;
  --secondary-bottom : #811a08;
  
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(96, 96, 96);
  border: 1px solid #adadad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-position: 0 -5px;
}

.btn--primary {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--primary-top) 0, var(--primary-bottom) 100%);
}

.btn--primary:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-bottom);
}

.btn--secondary {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--secondary-top) 0, var(--secondary-bottom) 100%);
}

.btn--secondary:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondary-bottom);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #279f43;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.15em 0.3em rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn--primary'> Primary </button>
<button class='btn btn--secondary'> Secondary </button>
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/GwarLJ)

Comment: You're not using the cascading action of custom properties, so you're not gaining anything by using them. Also the `active` state of your secondary button isn't working. Thanks for the reminder about custom properties though; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create additional selectors you should just use the child selector ability in the CSS.

```
.btn:nth-child(1) { background:linear-gradient(#000, #0000ff); }
.btn:nth-child(2) { background:linear-gradient(#000, #ff0000);}
```

Check out this fiddle for the full answer, hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/yash009/vgexcj86/

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address the fact that `.btn:hover` and `btn:active` depend on the color the button is initially colored to produce the appropriate effect. This correctly changes the initial color but as `.btn:hover`  was never modified and is not variable `.btn:hover` applies with the original/initial color